# unused cells background color

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView which displays about 5 cells at a time, yet in my table there might be cases where there are only 2 cells with content as seen on this picture:

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/30d3602979.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/30d3602979.png)

The white cells below do not look nice, how can I change the background color of these cells to black too? UITableView does not have a backgroundColor property.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `UITableView` inherits from `UIView`, and `UIView` always has a `backgroundColor`.

You can also change the background color to "non-opaque", and then change the background color of your parent container.

```
tableView.backgroundColor = // some UIColor
```

Comment: I am sorry, my bad, I misspelled the name of the table... Surely an array does not have a backgroundColor attribute :) Thanks!